# Getting all inner text of divs with same class

Tags: javascript

Is there way I can all inner html of all div with class="company Name".

Please guide me in right direction.

**Edit**

Can I use this in chrome console to get information out of a web page ?

Comment: Are you after "inner text" or "innerHTML"? They are different things.

Comment: @RobG inner text to be exact :)

Comment: *"Can I use this in chrome console"* You can execute any JS code in the console.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, what if I want to generate output in a text file, sorry for question over question, but I am in bit rush, sorry :)

Comment: Then you copy and paste the output of the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't use jquery for this. It's very easy with plain ol' javascript.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("[class='company Name']");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    //grab x[i].innerHTML (or textContent or innerText)
}
```

Comment: The selector can be ".someClass", which is less to type. ;-)

Comment: The correct selector would be `.same.class`. `.some .class` would look for all `.class` descendants of `.some` elements.

Answer (score 7):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6RbC3/4/)

**OPTION 1 - A one-liner**

```
var innerHTMLs = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName( 'company_name' ) ).map( function( x ){ return x.innerHTML } );

console.log( innerHTMLs );
```

**OPTION 2 - Slightly more verbose.**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'company_name' ),
    innerHTMLs = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i )
    innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML );
console.log( innerHTMLs );
```

**OPTION 3 - Should work on older browsers (IE8 and earlier) too.**

```
var innerHTMLs = [],
    elements   = document.getElementsByTagName( '*' ),
    classToMatch = 'bob';

for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i )
{
    if ( ( ' ' + elements[i].className + ' ' ).indexOf( ' ' + classToMatch + ' ' ) != -1 )
        innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML );
}

console.log( innerHTMLs );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain an array of [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) from elements containing `class="company Name"` using the following method:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('company Name'), e => e.innerText)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the strings in an array using jQuery:

```
var strings = [];

$('.yourclass').each(function(){
   strings.push( $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* Please provide a non-jQuery solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to start with this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('company name');
```

Then elements will be an array of all your divs.
After than iterate through them using a 'for in' and pull out the inner html for each one. Maybe something like this:

```
var allInnerHTML = '';

for (index in elements)
{
    var element = elements[index];

    allInnerHTML = allInnerHTML + element.innerHTML;
}
```

Not sure exactly what you're wanting to do but hopefully this will help.

Comment: If you are going to do *for..in* iteration over a host object (here a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname), which is not a good idea in this case), you must do a *hasOwnProperty* check and also check the property name is numeric to exclude unexpected properties and those that don't have a DOM element reference as the value. Given all that, it is much easier to do a normal iterative loop over the collection using an imcrementing counter (e.g. `for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)` so that you are guaranteed a DOM element every time.