# How to Get Value Using Class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple div

```
<div class="tknz-list">
    <div class="tknz-token" data-token="t"><span class="tknz-token-label">t</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
    <div class="tknz-token" data-token="u"><span class="tknz-token-label">u</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
    <div class="tknz-token" data-token="i"><span class="tknz-token-label">i</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
</div>
```

I want to access these span values (with each value) using their class name, but I cannot use any ids.

```
<span class="tknz-token-label">t</span>
<span class="tknz-token-label">x</span>
<span class="tknz-token-label">u</span>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can you try out way suggested in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `<span></span>` data which have the same class, You need to apply [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
span_array = [];//define array
  $(".tknz-token-label").each(function(){// iterate over same class spans
    console.log($(this).text()); // print the text of each span
    span_array.push($(this).text());// push span text to array
  });
  console.log(span_array); // you can save data an array for further use
  
  var final_string = span_array.join(); //join array value as string
  console.log(final_string); // check string 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tknz-list">
  <div class="tknz-token" data-token="t"><span class="tknz-token-label">t</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token" data-token="u"><span class="tknz-token-label">u</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token" data-token="i"><span class="tknz-token-label">i</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
</div>
```

Reference

[.join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Comment: can you please do one more answer ?                                                        How to store this value in a single variable like (var a = t,u,i)

Comment: Thank you so much your code work properly @Alive to Die

Comment: @aparnarai  glad to help you :):). I hope the explanation is enough to understand what I did there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to try like this as there is are more element with class

```
let span_text:string = [];
$(".tknz-token-label").each(function() {
  span_text.push($( this ).text());
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
var alltext= span_text.join();
console.log(alltext);
```

code above make use of [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to go through all element and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to print out text ob each element

Answer (score 2):

you can try this for more information you need check jquery . each method [jQuery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
$('.tknz-token-label').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tknz-list">
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="t"><span class="tknz-token-label">t</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="u"><span class="tknz-token-label">u</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="i"><span class="tknz-token-label">i</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try for .html() to after applying .each() on your span to get all span data, while .html() will not encode any characters.

```js
$('.tknz-token-label').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tknz-list">
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="t"><span class="tknz-token-label">t</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="u"><span class="tknz-token-label">u</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="i"><span class="tknz-token-label">i</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to store the values from the spans, place them in an array for later use. You can use map on the array from the class selector to accomplish this.

Simply reuse `vals` which will hold `["t","u","i"]`

```js
var vals = $(".tknz-token-label").toArray().map(t => $(t).text());
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tknz-list">
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="t"><span class="tknz-token-label">t</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="u"><span class="tknz-token-label">u</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
<div class="tknz-token" data-token="i"><span class="tknz-token-label">i</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `span` value with `$('selector').text()`. Here is example.

```js
$('.tknz-token-label').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tknz-list">
  <div class="tknz-token" data-token="t"><span class="tknz-token-label">t</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token" data-token="u"><span class="tknz-token-label">u</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
  <div class="tknz-token" data-token="i"><span class="tknz-token-label">i</span><span class="tknz-token-x">×</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Getting all inner text of divs with same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841079/getting-all-inner-text-of-divs-with-same-class)

There are many good ways to do it with javascript, and you don't have to just jquery.

What you are saying, is to get the document.textContent of divisions.

You can do that in many ways like:

```
Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName( 'company Name' ), e => e.innerText )
```

or

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("[class='company Name']");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
//grab x[i].innerHTML (or textContent or innerText)
}
```

like in the link at the top.

Comment: Hmm, two down voters and one voter. Oh well, just stating that this is a possible duplicate, and stating that you don't actually have to use jquery. Edit: what is going on, why are 1/2 of the people down voting, and 1/2 upvoting, my rep is changing from 11 to 9 to 19 to 21 to 23 to 11

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the complete DOM Structure

```
$('.tknz-list .tknz-token .tknz-token-label').each(function(){
 alert($(this).text());
});
```